# Deserialization issue (recursion object) using Jackson JSON

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I use Jackson JSON to serialise the `Game` object but it throws infinite loop exception because `Position` class contains `Island` class as `Game` class does.

According to this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) (part 3), I tried to add annotation `@JsonManagedReference` to `Game`'s `Island` field, and `@JsonBackReference` to `Position`'s `Island` field.

Serialization is running okay. However the following exception is thrown when I deserialize it:

```
Invalid type definition for type Position;: Can not bind back references as Creator parameters: type Position (reference 'defaultReference', parameter index #0)
```

What can I do to serialize/deserialize the `Game` object properly?
Here is the snippet of my classes.

**Game class**

```
public class Game {
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Island island;
   private Player player;

   @JsonCreator
   public Game(@JsonProperty("island")Island island, @JsonProperty("player")Player player) {
       this.island = island;
       this.player = player;
   }

   // other code ignored
}
```

**Player class**

```
public class Player {
   private Position position;
   private String name;

   @JsonCreator
   public Player(@JsonProperty("position")Position position, @JsonProperty("name")String name) {
       this.position = position;
       this.name = name;
   }

   // other code ignored
}
```

**Position class**

```
public class Position {
   private int row;
   private int column;
   @JsonBackReference
   private Island island

   @JsonCreator
   public Position(@JsonProperty("island")Island island, @JsonProperty("row")int row, @JsonProperty("column")int column) {
       this.island = island;
       this.row = row;
       this.column = column;
   }

   // other code ignored
}
```

**Island class**

```
public class Island {
   private final int numRows;
   private final int numColumns;

   @JsonCreator
   public Island(@JsonProperty("numRows")int numRows, @JsonProperty("numColumns")int numColumns) {
       this.numRows = numRows;
       this.numColumns = numColumns;
   }

   // other code ignored
}
```

Comment: Where did you set `@JsonBackReference`? Also your constructor of the `Player` class is wrong.

Comment: And how does your Island class look like?

Comment: @MuratK. I have put the annotation in the code. Player's constructor is a typo, just amended it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to put the `@JsonProperty` annotations on the member declarations?

Comment: @UweAllner I have put snippet of `Island` class with the JsonCreator as the class is really long.

Comment: @UweAllner No I didn't as I think it is not necessary unless I want to change the variable name showing in json?

Comment: Normally I only annotate the members (without specifiyng the name if it does not change), and I do not use own constructors, if it is not necessary. Just let Jackson use the default constructor, and fill all other values by accessor. Never encountered problems like this this way.